# How to get query string from a search input in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, search, twig

Once the user submits his search text from the input box, the goal is to show the search results in an url like this:

```
www.foo.com/search/<query_string>
```

Here is the html from the twig template:

```
<form 
    class="navbar-form" 
    method="get" 
    action="{{ path('path_id', {'searchTerm': app.request.query.get('search-term')}) }}" 
    role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search-term" id="search-term" required>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the route I've created in the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/search/{searchTerm}", defaults={"searchTerm" = null})
 * @Template()
 */
public function searchAction($searchTerm)
{
    return array('searchTerm' => $searchTerm);
}
```

I've set the search term to default to null, because if I don't do that, it gives an error message, since the `app.request.query.get` in the twig template it's not set if the user has not yet made a search.

The problem with this approach is that `$searchTerm` always arrives null in the `searchAction`, even when the user performs a search, and I don't know exactly why is this the case.

Any ideas how to fix this?

If this is in general a wrong approach in order to show search results, I would be thankful if someone could point me to a better solution. Bear in mind that I cannot use doctrine in this proyect because I have to use a cloud database, so I don't think a search engine bundle would work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately by submitting a form using `GET` you are effectively sending the browser to:

```
/search/?search-term=my%20search%20string
```

The Symfony router does not accept `POST` or `GET` variables as route parameters when you use the `/route/{parameter}` format, and you must either:

### Accept the `GET` parameter within the controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/search")
 * @Template()
 */
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    $searchTerm = $request->query->get('search-term');
    return array('searchTerm' => $searchTerm);
}
```

or

### Redirect the form request to the resulting route

```
/**
 * @Route("/searchSubmit")
 */
public function searchSubmitAction(Request $request)
{
    $searchTerm = $request->query->get('search-term');
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bundle_controller_search', array(
        'searchTerm' => $searchTerm,
    )));
}
```

You may also have to modify your search form to use `action="{{ path('path_id') }}"` without any initialized parameter (I'm not sure why you'd want to pass existing values into the action when you can just put it in `value=""` of the `input` tag.)